# C++ Is it possible to have a generic function pointer?

Tags: c++, function, generics, pointers

In C++ is it possible to make some sort of generic function pointer that points to any function that returns a pointer to some type and takes no arguments?

Eg, one type of pointer that can point to both of the following:

```
int* funcInt(){
    int* i = new int;
    *i = 5;
    return i;
}

char* funcChar(){
    char* c = new char;
    *c = 'a';
    return c;
}
```

Obviously the below is valid:

```
int* (*funcPointerA)() = funcInt;
char* (*funcPointerB)() = funcChar;
```

But is it possible to do something like the following (it gives a compile error at the moment):

```
void* (*funcPointerC)() = funcInt;
void* (*funcPointerD)() = funcChar;
```

Currently the above code gives the following error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'int* (*)()' to 'void* (*)()'
error: invalid conversion from 'char* (*)()' to 'void* (*)()'
```

Is there any way to cast the  funcPointerA and B to C and D?

This is so pointers to both types of functions (and others that return a pointer to some type while taking no arguments) can be stored together in a single vector.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard does not allow such thing. You may or may not be able to get away with casting your function pointer to `void* (*)()`. In C++ there are standard-conforming solutions. Here is a simple pre-C++11 one:

```
struct MyFunc
{
  virtual void* operator()() = 0;
  virtual ~Myfunc(){}
};

template <typename T>
struct MyfuncImpl
{
  typedef T TFunc();
  MyfuncImpl (TFunc* func) : m_func(func) {}
  void* operator()() { return m_func(); }
 private:
  TFunc* m_func;
};
```

Now you can store `shared_ptr<Myfunc>` in your vector.

A much nicer solution in C++11 could look like this:

```
template <typename T>
std::function<void*()> castToVoidFunc (T* (*func)())
{
  return [=](){ return func(); };
}
```

Comment: The standard _does_ allow casting function pointers, see [expr.reinterpret.cast]/6, it just doesn't allow calling them after the cast. The lambda in your C++11 solution is unnecessary, `std::function<R()>` will convert the return value to `R` if an implicit conversion sequence exists, so you can just `return std::function<void*()>(func);`

Comment: See [func.wrap.func]/2, which says calling `std::function` uses the _INVOKE(..., R)_ form, which [func.require]/2 defines as implicitly converting the result to `R`

Answer (score 9):

> Is there any way to cast the funcPointerA and B to C and D?

Yes, you can explicitly cast one type of function pointer to another type:

```
void* (*funcPointerC)() = reinterpret_cast<void*(*)()>(funcInt);
```

**But** it is undefined behaviour to call the result of the cast, you must cast it back to its original type first.  If you can record the original type and arrange for the pointer to be cast back to that original type then your code can work.

Comment: Okay, is there an easy way to store and later retrieve the type so it can be cast back?

Comment: Not really, you'd need to store some enum or integer code saying what the original type was, which means you have to know in advance all the possible types that you might want to store in the vector.  If you don't need the original type back and it's OK just to get `void*` back from calling the functions then @n.m.'s type erasure solution is simpler and cleaner

Comment: I need this to compare the identity of functions, not to call them, so this solution is great for me. Is it expected to work for member functions as well ?

Comment: @N0vember yes converting a pointer to member function to a different type of pointer to member function _and back again_ is valid. Doing anything with it before you convert it back again is undefined. You can't convert it to a pointer to a non-member function.