# Cross Compiler/Platform Naked Wrapper Function, Unconditional Jump to Function Pointer

Tags: c++, assembly, code-generation, function-pointers, wrapper

I'm working on a complex program that will have plugins calling functions, however the method for these functions will be selected at start-up, and assigned using a function pointer.

Rather than passing around function pointers I would Like to have some efficient wrapper functions in the main executable to call the appropriate function.

As this is for a plugin interface the calling convention will be defined either `__cdecl` or `__stdcall` depending on the build target (using macros), and the functions will be declare as `extern "C"`.

basically I want to be able to declare a SYMBOL in my executable, that the plugins can load as needed. For the different tasks that are need to solve a complex scientific problem, however there are a how range of solutions or methods getting the results for these tasks, these will be stored in plugins them selves so its easy to add new methods (no recompiling the entire application) this also makes it easier to share new methods as anyone with the base code can added any plugin requiring no experience them selves.

Any way I worked out I could either use this concept, or I would have to pass a function map to the plugins when I loaded them however the specifics of that function map depend upon the config and plugins that are loaded hence I don't actually know what it is until I'm finished loading plugins which would be a problem. Hence My Solution is store the map as a set of global variables in the main executable, accessible through wrapper functions.

However This is not straight forward as the functions have calling conventions which involve manipulating the stack after calling and before returning, which should be ignored on the wrapper, also it should perform a uncontitional jump `jmp` for intel x386 ASM rather than a function call `call` for intel x386 ASM, and control, should return from the jumped to function to the calling code not the wrapper. However I need C/C++ code to do this independent of Compiler/Platform/Processor.

Below is a basic concept example I throw to gather to test my idea and demonstrate what I want to do:

C++ code (Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 (specific))

```
#include <iostream>
void * pFunc;
int doit(int,int);
int wrapper(int, int);
int main() {
    pFunc = (void*)doit;
    std::cout << "Wrapper(2,3): " << wrapper(2,3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "doit(2,3):    " << doit(2,3) << std::endl;
    return 0; }
int doit(int a,int b) { return a*b; }
__declspec(naked) int wrapper(int, int) { __asm jmp pFunc }
```

Code has been tested to work properly, both calls output 6

ASM Output for wrapper and doit

```
PUBLIC  ?wrapper@@YAHHH@Z               ; wrapper
; Function compile flags: /Odtp
;   COMDAT ?wrapper@@YAHHH@Z
_TEXT   SEGMENT
___formal$ = 8                      ; size = 4
___formal$ = 12                     ; size = 4
?wrapper@@YAHHH@Z PROC                  ; wrapper, COMDAT
; File c:\users\glen fletcher\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test_wrapper\test_wrapper.cpp
; Line 15
    jmp DWORD PTR ?pFunc@@3PAXA         ; pFunc
?wrapper@@YAHHH@Z ENDP                  ; wrapper
_TEXT   ENDS
PUBLIC  ?doit@@YAHHH@Z                  ; doit
; Function compile flags: /Ogtp
;   COMDAT ?doit@@YAHHH@Z
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_a$ = 8                         ; size = 4
_b$ = 12                        ; size = 4
?doit@@YAHHH@Z PROC                 ; doit, COMDAT
; Line 14
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _a$[ebp]
    imul    eax, DWORD PTR _b$[ebp]
    pop ebp
    ret 0
?doit@@YAHHH@Z ENDP                 ; doit
; Function compile flags: /Ogtp
_TEXT   ENDS
```

Nonwrapper ASM for wrapper

```
PUBLIC wrapper
_1$ = 8
_2$ = 12
_TEXT SEGMENT
wrapper PROC
   push ebp
   mov ebp, esp
   mov eax, DWORD PTR _2$[ebp]
   push eax
   mov ecx, DWORD PTR _1$[ebp]
   push ecx
   call DWORD PTR pFunc
   add esp, 8
   pop ebp
   ret 0
wrapper ENDP
_TEXT ENDS
```

How can I get the original code generated in a cross-platform and cross-compiler manner?? As opposed to the standard for a C/C++ function with the epilog and prolog code generated by the compiler, NOTE don't want to make assumptions about the processor either so can't do a separate ASM file, want compiler to generate the code with just the unconditional jump statement.

`goto` doesn't work as pFunc is a variable not a label, not even sure it `goto` would work between functions anyway.

Comment: `...can I get the original code generated in a ... cross-compiler manner?` What form would that be in exactly in your mind? You're working with assembly, by definition that is going to be platform specific.

Comment: For some reason, SO references in the answer doesn't get picked up as 'linked', so see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16146521/512360 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/16508749/512360 as well.

Comment: @greatwolf the code is in C++, see first code box, for the test I run to verify the concept would word in Visual C++ 2010. I want a function symbol in the executable such that it immediately access an address stored in a global variable "pFunc" and then performs an unconditional jump to that location. This address would be to a function stored in a dynamically loaded library "plugin" which would have the same calling structure, i.e. return type, argument, calling convention. Hence its a wrapper around a function pointer which another "plugin" can easily call to execute the handler function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as your question,

> How can I get the original code generated in a cross-platform and cross-compiler manner?

goes, the answer is "not at all".

Function calling conventions are *deep into platform and compiler / language specifics*. You're touching what's called the *ABI* (Application binary interface); issues like:

- how / where are parameters passed from caller to called function, for all numbers / types / ordering of parameters ?
- how are "hidden" features of the language (like C++ `this`) implemented ?
- what are the rules for register usage (which regs are clobbered by making a function call to the "target context") ?
- how / where are return values, for all types of "returning a value" ?
- does source (caller) and target (callee) context use the same data structure layout rules ?
- how can you deal with processor operating state changes (like would occur if you try to call 32bit code while executing in 64bit mode, and/or vice versa) ?

I've given a similar answer [in this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16146521/512360), then particularly targeted for a question about doing a "downcalls" 64bit Windows --> 32bit Windows `stdcall`. Alas, not much to add there except "it's complicated, not generally possible and *always* very strongly code/compiler and OS-dependent".

This can be done in a *specific* case (the technical term is "thunking". Every "thunk" is very specific: say, if you know the called function uses 32bit Windows/x86 style `fastcall` and has a single parameter, you can write a "thunk" doing the interfacing (and possibly processor state switch) that'd allow you to call it from, say, 64bit Linux code. That thunk would be different from one where the first parameter is a floating-point value passed in `XMM0`, though ... and so on.

For the general case ... refer to [the infinite heap of programming knowledge that's SO again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508749/c-is-it-possible-to-have-a-generic-function-pointer), sorry, there *is no generic function pointer* :(

**Edit:**
if the concern is code generation, then try the following:

```
/* sourcefile 1 */
extern void (*p)(char *, ...);

static __inline__ void wrapper(char *arg, char *s) {
    return p(arg, s);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    wrapper("Hello, I am %s\n", argv[0]);
    return 0;
}

/* sourcefile 2 */
extern void printf(char*, ...);
void (*p)(char *, ...) = printf;
```

If I compile those two, using `gcc` *with optimization*, the compiler creates the following code for `main`:

```
0000000000400500 <main>:
  400500:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  400504:       48 8b 36                mov    (%rsi),%rsi
  400507:       bf 0c 06 40 00          mov    $0x40060c,%edi
  40050c:       ff 15 d6 03 10 00       callq  *1049558(%rip)        # 5008e8 <p>
  400512:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  400514:       48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  400518:       c3                      retq
```

which is pretty much what you want - except it *eliminates* `wrapper()`, but directly inlines the call through the function pointer.

Comment: The wrapper function should just jump to the address of a C/C++ function pointer of the same type as the wrapper function, with out first doing any stack manipulation, such that when the function pointer function returns it returns to whatever called the wrapper as if it had just called the pointer. Also As its for a plugin system all functions will be extern "C" to removing name mangling, so there would be no this argument/variable, and all code should same platform, and processor state. I can do this by passing appropriate pointers to my plugins, but this would require multistage loading.

Comment: @glenflet: the wrapper would then be something like `static int wrapper(int a, int b) { int (*p)(int, int) = (int(*)(int, int))pFunc; return p(a, b): }` as the tail recursion will do what you hope to see there. But since the original funcs might have _different_ return types, a single wrapper is not sufficient AFAICS.

Comment: I know I can do that sort of wrapper, however since the function pointed to by the function pointer is known to be the same  function signature thus have the same prolog and epilog, I would like to get the compiler to output a simple unconditional jump to the location stored by the pointer, hence all the wrapper function should do is change the Instruction Pointer, leave the rest of the processor state alone, and let the pointed to function think it had been called directly rather than through the wrapper.

Comment: @glenflet: Which compiler are you using ? `gcc`, in the versions I've tried, does _exactly_ that if you use a `static int` (possibly `static __inline__ int`) for the wrapper, and you compile with optimization.

Comment: That's not exactly what I was looking for, as the calling code would be an external module hence the code couldn't inline. Consider Module 2, calls symbol X in module 1 as (int(*)(int,int)), which is a native ASM command to jump (i.e. JMP) to the address stored in pX, where pX "currently" holds the address of Xv2_3 in Module 3, and Module 2, and Module 3 where dynamically loaded at run time by module 1, this in effect allow you to change the function executed when module 2 executes the function call, with the extra overhead of just the unconditional jump command. For multiple compilers.

Comment: (Cont.), The easiest method would be to write ASM code which I could do for x86 ASM code, however doing so would limit the portability of the code. I expect that their is no universal solution, but something could be done with macros, i.e. from what I've read __asm__ "X: jmp pX"; would work on GCC for x86 if placed outside any functions, as it will just output the label and command this could then be exported as a symbol. Do you have any solution for other CPUS/ASM languages and for other compilers? Would be good for reference, Despite the fact I found another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a solution to my problem, rather than using naked functions or passing a list of function pointers.

I can pass a pointer to a struct of function pointers i.e.

```
struct Functions {
   bool (AppAPI *logInfo(std::string,...)),
   bool (AppAPI *logWarn(std::string,...)),
   bool (AppAPI *logError(std::string,...)),
   bool (AppAPI *registerFunction(std::string,void *))
   ...
} PluginFunctions;

for (int i = 0;i<plugins;i++) {
   plugin[i].initialize(&PluginFunctions)
}

PluginFunctions.logInfo = LogInfo;
...
```

As the plugin init function, is passed a pointer to the struct it can store this and then load the current value of the function pointer from memory, the struct is just a table of pointer in memory, the function pointers can be set after the struct has been passed to the plugin and it still updates the plugin.